# Modifying an image for angled projection (Inkscape)

Tags: inkscape

I'm very new to graphic design programs and I may be dealing with a limitation, I'm not sure.

I am trying to edit an image so that, when projected through lens at an angle it will appear to be the original image.

I've drawn the shape based on an algorithm I wrote for 25 degrees and a light cone of 36.48 degrees.

I'll attach the original and the shape it needs to fit below.

I've tried plenty of methods, interpolation, envelope, extrude, perspective etc. all seem to destroy the image as it doesn't like moving the object as a while, rather a collection of different object (or paths).

Can anyone assist with a way that I can make a controlled distortion to this image?

PS, this is one of many images, thus I would prefer a method that may take time to set up, but not too long to repeat.

PPS, if someone is aware of another program that is capable of this easily, I'm willing to try it!

THANKS!

Image here->[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prYbI.png)

Comment: This is unclear. To get a good answer, tell us what you want about 1)the leftmost single stroke heavily distorted circle 2)the rightmost colored shape. Should one of those to be transformed to another or is the whole 2 shape image the one and only image that you want to get projected? At least one thing is sure: If the leftmost shape is a circle as seen, when projected onto something, that something must be quite a complex surface..

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, Rory. Are you perhaps planning to obtain an oblique [anamorphosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anamorphosis) (see also [here](https://www.anamorphosis.com/index.html) and [here](https://anamorphicart.wordpress.com/tag/creating-anamorphoses/))?

Comment: Hello, and thank you. Yes indeed it seems what I am trying to achieve is an anamoprphosis.

What I am trying to do is to 'reverse engineer a perspective image'...

The desired result would be to 'squish' the coloured shape such that when projected onto the floor at an angle (not perpendicular to the ground) the image appears to be a circle. the distorted shape is what i believe i need to 'squish' the coloured shape into, to achieve a circle when projected at 25 degrees..

I hope this helps clarify?

Comment: Something like the [Keystone effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystone_effect)? Perhaps you need just to arrange the perspective of the image. See [here](http://fomori.org/blog/?p=59). You can also give a look to [GIMP](https://www.thoughtco.com/correcting-perspective-distortion-with-gimp-1701638) or [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/tutorials/perspective/en.shtml). Try and let us know...

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Paolo!. Finally downloaded GIMP (work computer) and though I am very slow at using it, the 'cage transform' process seems to do exactly as I want! I have a long way to go in terms of being able to systematically reproduce this application many times but a huge step in the right direction.

(Currently I just click and drag each node point - which if I want to be accurate means moving 360 nodes per image)....
So if you're aware of a better way to do this I'd love to know!
many thanks for your help so far!